# Why is NSString property not seeing changes to an NSMutableString assigned to it?

Tags: objective-c

I have this class:

```
@interface XYZPerson : NSObject{

NSString *_myNonPropertyInstanceVariable;
}

@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *lastName;
@property NSDate *dateOfBirth;
@property (readonly) NSString* fullName;

@property (nonatomic)NSString* experimental;

-(void)sayHello;
- (void)saySomething:(NSString *)greeting;
+(id)person;

- (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName lastName:(NSString *)aLastName
            dateOfBirth:(NSDate *)aDOB;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "XYZPerson.h"

@implementation XYZPerson {
    NSString *_myNonPropertyInstanceVariable2;

}
@synthesize experimental = _experimental;


-(id)init{
    self = [self initWithFirst:@"John" andLastName:@"Doe"];

    return self;
}

-(id) initWithFirst:(NSString*)first andLastName:(NSString*)last{
    return [self initWithFirstName:first lastName:last dateOfBirth:nil];
}

- (id)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)aFirstName lastName:(NSString *)aLastName
            dateOfBirth:(NSDate *)aDOB{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        _firstName = aFirstName;
        _lastName = aLastName;
        _dateOfBirth = aDOB;
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)sayHello{
    NSString* greet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, World! %@",self.fullName ];
    [self saySomething:greet];
}


-(void)saySomething:(NSString *)greeting {
    NSLog(@"%@", greeting);
}

+(id)person{
    return [[self alloc]init];
}

-(NSString*)fullName{

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",_firstName,_lastName];
}

-(void) setExperimental:(NSString *)anExperimental{
    _experimental = anExperimental;
}

-(NSString*) experimental{
    return @"Balls to you";
}
```

In my main method, I do:

```
NSMutableString* firstName = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"IntheBeggining"];
        NSString* secondName = @"MyLastName";
        XYZPerson* newP = [[XYZPerson alloc]initWithFirstName:firstName lastName:secondName dateOfBirth:nil];
        firstName = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"Awesome"];
        [newP sayHello];
```

Now I expected that since firstName is a mutable string, when I change it to "Awesome", it should be reflected in the sayHello invocation... but instead the output is:

> Hello, World! IntheBeggining MyLastName

It should have said "Hello,World! Awesome MyLastName" ..Why didn't the new value of the NSMutableString* be reflected in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You doesn't change the content of the mutable string of the first line in your last snippet. You just change the reference `firstName` is pointing to. To change the content use `setString:`:

```
[firstName setString:@"Awesome"];
```

This will change the first name of the person, too.

BTW: it is not a good design if the content of properties can be changed from outside it's maintaining class. It's better to use copied properties, which will copy the content of mutable strings to immutable strings on assignments:

```
@property (copy) NSString *firstName;
```

You can change the first name of a `XYZPerson` by invoking its setter:

```
newP.firstName = @"Awesome";
```

This has the advantage that the maintaining can keep control over the value. Suppose if you want store the full name in a new (hidden) property. If code outside of the class are changing the value of `firstName` by `setString:`, the class has no chance to observe this change and update the full name. If you forbid the assignment of mutable string, you just need to overwrite the setter to keep the full name up-to-date.